# React redux, reducers and back end

Tags: reactjs, redux

i have a backend that return me several products from different categories

And on my front end I need to filter this categories,

And so I thought, it would be better to send backend with all these categories already filtered into objects,

or filter through redux, using reducer something like:

```
      categoryA: action.data.filter(conditionA),
      categoryB: action.data.filter(conditionB),
      categoryC: action.data.filter(conditionC),
```

That is, by getting the response from the back end filtering the categories,
or would I better filter the categories in the back end

which would be ideal?

Comment: Its better to filter data on server side to reduce processing overhead on client side

Comment: thanks @NoumanJanjua !!

Comment: if u want awnser for vote up.

Comment: This is impossible to answer in general terms. How much data is in the response and how complicated is the filtering? Both can be valid approaches depending on your circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to filter data on server side to reduce processing overhead on client side

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pKnYwQx5 
My code ended up getting too big could I improve on something?

If you can help me I'm grateful

Comment: The processing overhead on the client side can be minimal. In some cases it might be a better implementation to filter on the client side. It's hard to answer without the exact details. These blanket statements just confuse people.